# How to set restTemplate parameter type?

Tags: spring, rest, type-conversion, resttemplate, bad-request

Here is my code

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> vars = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    vars.add("name", fileName);
    vars.add("parent", "43");
    vars.add("size_s3", size_s3);
    vars.add("size_ssg", size_ssg);
    vars.add("size", size);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization","token "+user.getToken());
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(vars, headers);
    result = restTemplate.exchange(RestInfo.restURL+"/files", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class).getBody();
```

the httpClientErrorException is 400 BAD REQUEST

{"size_s3": ["Enter a whole number."], "parent": ["Incorrect type.  Expected pk value, received list."], "size": ["Enter a whole number."]}

I think prameter type problem. so i tried to change my code like this

vars.add("size_s3", Integer.parseInt(size_s3));

but results are same...

how to set restTemplate parameter type?

help me plz!

Answer (score 0):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

MultiValueMap<String, Object> vars = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
vars.add("name", fileName);
vars.add("parent", 43);
vars.add("size_s3", size_s3);
vars.add("size_ssg", size_ssg);
vars.add("size", size);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization","token "+user.getToken());
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(vars, headers);
result = restTemplate.exchange(RestInfo.restURL+"/files", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class).getBody();
```

i will make some changes in your code try it